# python webdriver keyerror session

Tags: python, selenium

When I try:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
```

Error occurs as following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "test2.py", line 11, in <module>
browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
 File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox \webdriver.py", line 150, in __init__
keep_alive=True)
 File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
 File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 180, in start_session
self.session_id = response['sessionId']
KeyError: 'sessionId'
```

Python-2.7, selenium 3.0.2, firefox 52.0.1

**How to fix the error?**

Comment: update your selenium to latest version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use geckodriver version 0.15 and selenium 3.3.0+ with firefox 52

Answer (score 0):

This was driving me nuts (no pun intended). I tried a lot of variations of FF, selenium & geckodriver until I hit upon:

- Selenium 3.4.1
- Firefox 52.0
- Geckodriver 0.13.0

I think the geckodriver was the key, may work with other combos of FF and selenium but this works for my purposes.

This is python 3.6 on Mint 18.